# How to trigger of window state in any component style WPF

Tags: wpf

This is code i use to hide button when window is maximized, but this trigger work only if window is maximized on startup

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ScaleButton">
    ...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Window.WindowState" Value="Maximized">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It seems like trigger checks only once

Comment: WindowState is not a Button property, hence such a Trigger can't work. You may want to use a DataTrigger with an appropriate Binding.

Comment: Yep, DataTrigger is what i need, thanks @Clemens

Answer (score 1):

Use DataTrigger to access ancestor properties

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ScaleButton">
    ...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="Maximized">
            <Setter Property="<REQUIRED_PROP>" Value="<NEW_VALUE>" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```